# Convert Column Data to Row based on Identity column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
ID      Time-in-out
1122    08:00
1122    17:00
221     09:00
221     15:00
```

And I need an output like this:

```
ID     Time-in    Time-Out
1122   08:00      17:00 
221    09:00      15:00
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT, time_in_out TIME(0));

INSERT INTO tab(id, time_in_out)
SELECT 1122, '08:00'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1122, '17:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  221, '09:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  221, '15:00'

SELECT
   [id], 
   [time_in]    = MIN(time_in_out),
   [time_out]   = MAX(time_in_out)
FROM tab t
GROUP BY id
```

Alternatively you can use PIVOT.